# How to combine two result sets with same columns but different case statement and a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, union

How can I use 'union' for the the two following query? or is there any other solution? They both run successfully and return the result set I expect. They have same number of columns(using same tables and same data types) but differ in case statements and in a 'where' clause.

```
  SELECT TOP 720
            ind_first_name AS [First Name],
            ind_last_name AS [Last Name],
            cst_recno AS [Member ID],
            cst_eml_address_dn AS [Email Address],
            adr_city AS City,
            adr_state AS [State],
            adr_country AS Country,
            cst_org_name_dn AS Company,
            cst_ixo_title_dn AS [Job Title],
CASE
WHEN mem_member_product LIKE '%Stud%' 
      THEN 'Associate Student'
ELSE 'Exclude'
END AS [Member Type]
    FROM co_individual 
    INNER JOIN co_individual_ext  ON ind_cst_key_ext = ind_cst_key 
    INNER JOIN co_customer ON cst_key = ind_cst_key 
        AND ind_delete_flag=0
        AND ind_deceased_flag=0 
    LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address ON cst_cxa_key = cxa_key 
    LEFT JOIN co_address ON adr_key = cxa_adr_key 
    LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type ON cst_key = mem_cst_key 
    WHERE mem_member_type IS NOT NULL and mem_expire_date >= 9/7/2017 and mem_member_product LIKE '%Stud%'
    AND adr_country = N'UNITED STATES' 
    AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 
    AND ind_key_leader_flag_ext != 1 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Staff' 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Spouse' 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Press'
    order by newid()


SELECT TOP 80
            ind_first_name AS [First Name],
            ind_last_name AS [Last Name],
            cst_recno AS [Member ID],
            cst_eml_address_dn AS [Email Address],
            adr_city AS City,
            adr_state AS [State],
            adr_country AS Country,
            cst_org_name_dn AS Company,
            cst_ixo_title_dn AS [Job Title],
CASE
WHEN Mem_member_type in ('Full Under 35 Sustaining','Full Member') and ind_age_cp <= '35'
      THEN 'Full Member Under 35'
ELSE 'Exclude'
END AS [Member Type]
    FROM co_individual 
    INNER JOIN co_individual_ext  ON ind_cst_key_ext = ind_cst_key 
    INNER JOIN co_customer ON cst_key = ind_cst_key 
        AND ind_delete_flag=0
        AND ind_deceased_flag=0 
    LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address ON cst_cxa_key = cxa_key 
    LEFT JOIN co_address ON adr_key = cxa_adr_key 
    LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type ON cst_key = mem_cst_key 
    WHERE mem_member_type IS NOT NULL and mem_expire_date >= 9/7/2017 and mem_member_type in ('Full Under 35 Sustaining','Full Member') and ind_age_cp <= '35'
    AND adr_country = N'UNITED STATES' 
    AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 
    AND ind_key_leader_flag_ext != 1 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Staff' 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Spouse' 
    AND ind_int_code != N'Press'
        order by newid ()
```

Thank you.

Comment: well what happens when you union them?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just put UNION between the two queries, wrap the whole thing in parentheses, give it an alias, and select from it:

```
Select * from 
(
SELECT TOP 720
        ind_first_name AS [First Name],
        ind_last_name AS [Last Name],
        cst_recno AS [Member ID],
        cst_eml_address_dn AS [Email Address],
        adr_city AS City,
        adr_state AS [State],
        adr_country AS Country,
        cst_org_name_dn AS Company,
        cst_ixo_title_dn AS [Job Title],
        CASE
            WHEN mem_member_product LIKE '%Stud%' 
              THEN 'Associate Student'
            ELSE 'Exclude'
        END AS [Member Type]
FROM co_individual 
INNER JOIN co_individual_ext  ON ind_cst_key_ext = ind_cst_key 
INNER JOIN co_customer ON cst_key = ind_cst_key 
    AND ind_delete_flag=0
    AND ind_deceased_flag=0 
LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address ON cst_cxa_key = cxa_key 
LEFT JOIN co_address ON adr_key = cxa_adr_key 
LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type ON cst_key = mem_cst_key 
WHERE mem_member_type IS NOT NULL and mem_expire_date >= '9/7/2017' and mem_member_product LIKE '%Stud%'
AND adr_country = N'UNITED STATES' 
AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 
AND ind_key_leader_flag_ext != 1 
AND ind_int_code != N'Staff' 
AND ind_int_code != N'Spouse' 
AND ind_int_code != N'Press'
order by newid()

UNION

SELECT TOP 80
        ind_first_name AS [First Name],
        ind_last_name AS [Last Name],
        cst_recno AS [Member ID],
        cst_eml_address_dn AS [Email Address],
        adr_city AS City,
        adr_state AS [State],
        adr_country AS Country,
        cst_org_name_dn AS Company,
        cst_ixo_title_dn AS [Job Title],
        CASE
            WHEN Mem_member_type in ('Full Under 35 Sustaining','Full Member') and ind_age_cp <= '35'
              THEN 'Full Member Under 35'
            ELSE 'Exclude'
        END AS [Member Type]
FROM co_individual 
INNER JOIN co_individual_ext  ON ind_cst_key_ext = ind_cst_key 
INNER JOIN co_customer ON cst_key = ind_cst_key 
    AND ind_delete_flag=0
    AND ind_deceased_flag=0 
LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address ON cst_cxa_key = cxa_key 
LEFT JOIN co_address ON adr_key = cxa_adr_key 
LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type ON cst_key = mem_cst_key 
WHERE mem_member_type IS NOT NULL and mem_expire_date >= 9/7/2017 and mem_member_type in ('Full Under 35 Sustaining','Full Member') and ind_age_cp <= '35'
AND adr_country = N'UNITED STATES' 
AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 
AND ind_key_leader_flag_ext != 1 
AND ind_int_code != N'Staff' 
AND ind_int_code != N'Spouse' 
AND ind_int_code != N'Press'
    order by newid ()
) as Unioned_Query
```

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Comment: It was an answer in the form of an instruction rather than in the form of "here is the code for you".

Comment: Thank you, Brian. It worked out great. I noticed I have a few duplicates among my result set. Is there a way to add a distinct function on top of that query that would pull all unique [Member ID] ? @Brian

Comment: To clarify, from the query above I get all unique values.

Comment: However, I added two more union queries. I copied the two case statements here:     1. CASE WHEN Mem_member_type in ('Full Under 35 Sustaining','Full Member') and ind_age_cp <= '35' THEN 'Full Member Under 35'                                                                                                       2. CASE WHEN Mem_member_type IN ('Full Member', 'Full MemberULI, 'Full Private Member', 'Full Sustaining') THEN 'Private Full Member' . So, I am pulling data in two union queries from the same member type (Full Member) and I believe that's why I get a few duplicates.

Comment: In the outer "select *" query, use "select distinct *" instead.  And of course, in production code you should use explicit field names.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I have added the follow up question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094999/how-to-do-a-distinct-expression-on-top-of-a-union-query

Comment: I'll take a look at that later.  If this meets your needs, be sure to mark it as the answer - this will help other users find it if they have a similar issue.